# javascript replaceChild doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm a student of Computer science and we are making exercises on javascript the exercises was:
"Replace item number 4 by a new item with id "numberFour" and with text "Mistreatment"."
 this is how it looked before i made the exercise:

1. Number one: Looking For a Mate
2. Number two: Boredom
3. Number three: Lack of Obedience
4. Number four: Mistreatment
5. Number five: Seeking Companionship

then i wrote this js code to complete the assignment:

```
var vier = document.createElement("li");
vier.innerHTML = "Number four: Mistreatment";
vier.setAttribute("id", "numberFour");
var lijst = document.querySelector("#fiveReasons");
lijst.replaceChild(vier, lijst.childNodes[3]);
```

and then it looked like this:

1. Number one: Looking For a Mate
2. Number two: Boredom
3. Number four: Mistreatment
4. Number four: Mistreatment
5. Number five: Seeking Companionship

so i changed this my code to this:

```
var vier = document.createElement("li");
vier.innerHTML = "Number four: Mistreatment";
vier.setAttribute("id", "numberFour");
var lijst = document.querySelector("#fiveReasons");
lijst.replaceChild(vier, lijst.childNodes[4]);
```

and then i got this:

1. Number one: Looking For a Mate
2. Number two: Boredom
3. Number three: Lack of Obedience
4. Number four: Mistreatment
5. Number four: Mistreatment
6. Number five: Seeking Companionship

My teacher doesn't get why it won't work and me neither, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`childNodes` includes text nodes for whitespace between your `li` elements (and comment nodes if any, etc.). Use `children` if you want just child **elements**:

```js
var vier = document.createElement("li");
vier.innerHTML = "Number four: Mistreatment - updated";
vier.setAttribute("id", "numberFour");
var lijst = document.querySelector("#fiveReasons");
lijst.replaceChild(vier, lijst.children[3]);
```

```html
<ol id="fiveReasons">
    <li>Number one: Looking For a Mate</li>
    <li>Number two: Boredom</li>
    <li>Number three: Lack of Obedience</li>
    <li>Number four: Mistreatment</li>
    <li>Number five: Seeking Companionship</li>
</ol>
```

`children` works on all modern browsers, and IE8.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) collection also includes text nodes (white spaces, line breaks, tabs, etc.), so they are also counted. Try [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) instead:

```
lijst.replaceChild(vier, lijst.children[3]);
```